# Unexpected Identifier in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm attempting to run a code with node.js and currently I am getting the error:

> Unexpected identifier

The code file is as follows:

```
/*
This script will bruteforce a live match from the TPP API
in Defiance mode and estimate winrates.
Requirements:
-An oauth for the TPP API: https://twitchplayspokemon.tv/show_oauth_token
-Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
-sync-request for Node.js: `npm install -g sync-request` (NPM should come 
installed with Node.js)
-Pokemon Showdown: https://github.com/Zarel/Pokemon-Showdown
You don't need to install its dependencies, the simulator itself does not 
require them.
-My PBR mod for Pokemon Showdown: https://github.com/mathfreak231/random- 
showdown-mods
enter code here`enter code here`This is required to accurately simulate PBR. 
Note that it is still in development.
Setup steps:
Copy the pbr directory from random-showdown-mods into Pokemon-Showdown/mods.
Fill in the relative path to Pokemon-Showdown/sim below
Fill in your TPP API oauth token below
Change the number constants if you wish
Then just `node defiancechan.js`, sit back, and enjoy your simulation!
Note that the PBR mod is *not* entirely accurate. Known inaccuracies 
include,
but are not limited to: draws are not handled properly, and Fury Cutter
still resets when it shouldn't.
*/

// Replace this with a relative path to Pokemon-Showdown/sim
const Sim = require('./../Pokemon-Showdown/sim');

// Replace this with your TPP oauth token
const TPP_OAUTH = "abc123xyz69420";

// Absolute maximum sample size.
const MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE = 1000;

// z* for your desired confidence level. This is used to calculate
// the margin of sampling error. Some common values:
// For 95% confidence: 1.959963986
// For 99% confidence: 2.575829303
// In practice this means that C% of your simulations will
// have the true proportion within the margin of error from
// the sampled proportion.
// If you don't know what any of this means, don't bother changing
// or paying attention to the "Margin of error" output at the end.
const Z_STAR = 2.575829303;

// Maximum time to run the simulation for, in milliseconds.
const MAX_TIME = 30000;

// If this is true, it prints some match logs (1 in DEBUG_EVERY) to stdout 
while it's bashing them.
const DEBUG = false;
const DEBUG_EVERY = 50;

// Set this to require a .json file to bash a match there instead of a live 
match.
const TEST_MATCH_PATH = null;

/////////////////////////////////////////
// DON'T EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE //
/////////////////////////////////////////
const request = require('sync-request');

const PBR_FORMAT = {
  id: 'tppbr',
  name: 'TPPBR',
  mod: 'pbr',
  ruleset: ["PBR Sleep Clause", "PBR Freeze Clause", "PBR Self-Destruct 
Clause", "PBR Destiny Bond Clause"],
  banlist: [],
  unbanlist: [],
  debug: true,
}

/**
  * because pokecat TriHard
  */
function convert_stats_table(stats) {
  let newstats = {};
  for (statname in stats) {
    newstats[statname.toLowerCase()] = stats[statname];
  }
  return newstats;
}

function main() {
  console.log("Getting current match...");
  let match;
  if (TEST_MATCH_PATH) {
    match = require(TEST_MATCH_PATH);
  } else {
    const res = request('GET', 
"https://twitchplayspokemon.tv/api/current_match", {
      headers: {
        'OAuth-Token': TPP_OAUTH
      },
    });
    match = JSON.parse(res.getBody('utf8'));
  }
  console.log("Done.");
  if ((match.base_gimmicks.includes('blind_bet') || 
match.base_gimmicks.includes('secrecy')) && !match.started) {
    throw new Error("Can't analyze a match unless all the Pokemon have been 
revealed.");
  }
  if (!match.base_gimmicks.includes('defiance')) {
    console.log("WARNING: This is not a defiance match!");
  }

  const startTime = Date.now();
  let wincounter = {
    Blue: 0,
    Red: 0,
    draw: 0,
  };
  let teams = [[], []];
  for (let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    for (const pokemon of match.teams[i]) {
      teams[i].push({
        name: pokemon.ingamename,
        species: pokemon.species.name, // TODO: handle forms
        item: pokemon.item.name,
        ability: pokemon.ability.name,
        moves: pokemon.moves.map(move => move.name),
        nature: pokemon.nature.name,
        gender: pokemon.gender ? pokemon.gender.toUpperCase() : 'N',
        evs: convert_stats_table(pokemon.evs),
        ivs: convert_stats_table(pokemon.ivs),
        level: pokemon.level,
        shiny: pokemon.shiny,
        happiness: pokemon.happiness,
      });
    }
  }

  const isRandomOrder = match.base_gimmicks.includes('random_order');
  const isTraitor = match.base_gimmicks.includes('traitor');
  const isFog = match.base_gimmicks.includes('fog');

  let battle;
  let i;
  console.log("Begin simulation of matches...");
  for (i = 1; i <= MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE; i++) {
    battle = new Sim.Battle({
       formatid: PBR_FORMAT,
    });
    // prevent battle from starting so we can edit stuff first
    battle.started = true;

    let newTeams = teams;
    if (isRandomOrder || isTraitor) {
      // TODO: In what order are these gimmicks applied?
      newTeams = battle.deepClone(teams);
      if (isRandomOrder) {
        for (let team of newTeams) {
           battle.shuffle(team);
        }
      }
      if (isTraitor) {
        // swap 2 pokes, same position
        const p = battle.random(3);
        const temp = newTeams[0][p];
        newTeams[0][p] = newTeams[1][p];
        newTeams[1][p] = temp;
      }
    }

    battle.join('p1', 'Blue', 1, newTeams[0]);
    battle.join('p2', 'Red', 2, newTeams[1]);

    for (const side of battle.sides) {
      for (const pokemon of side.pokemon) {
        pokemon.originalPosition = pokemon.position;
        for (const [m, move] of pokemon.baseMoveSlots.entries()) {
          // change move PP
          const moveData = battle.getMove(move.id);
          const oldMoveData = match.teams[side.n] 
   [pokemon.position].moves[m];
          move.pp = oldMoveData.pp;
          move.maxpp = moveData.pp * (5 + oldMoveData.pp_ups) / 5;
        }
        pokemon.clearVolatile(); // actually update the moveslots TriHard
      }
    }

    if (match.stage) {
      battle.colosseum = match.stage;
    } else if (isFog && battle.randomChance(1,2)) {
      // TODO: confirm this is correct
      battle.colosseum = 'courtyard';
    } else {
      battle.colosseum = battle.sample([
        'gateway', 'mainstreet', 'waterfall', 'neon', 'crystal',
        'sunnypark', 'magma', 'sunset', 'stargazer', 'lagoon',
      ]);
    }

    battle.started = false;
    battle.start();

    if (isFog) battle.setWeather('fog');

    while (!battle.ended) {
      if (battle.turn > 500) {
        console.log('===BEGIN BAD MATCH LOG EXPORT===');
        console.log(battle.log.join('\n'));
        console.log('===END BAD MATCH LOG EXPORT===');
        console.log('===BEGIN BAD MATCH INPUT LOG EXPORT===');
        console.log(battle.inputLog.join('\n'));
        console.log('===END BAD MATCH INPUT LOG EXPORT===');
        throw new Error("The match fucked up somehow.");
      }
      for (const side of battle.sides) {
        let result;
        switch (side.currentRequest) {
          case 'switch':
            // TPPBR switching rules.
            let target = null;
            for (let i = side.active.length; i < side.pokemon.length; i++) {
              const pokemon = side.pokemon[i];
              if (!(pokemon.fainted) && (!target || pokemon.originalPosition 
< target.originalPosition)) {
                target = pokemon;
              }
            }
            result = battle.choose(side.id, `switch ${target.position + 
1}`);
            if (!result) throw new Error(side.choice.error);
            break;
      case 'move':
        // Same as TPPBR, choose random moves until one works
        let tries = 0;
        do {
          result = battle.choose(side.id, `move ${battle.random(4) + 1}`);
          if (++tries > 50) throw new Error(`${side.id} stuck on a move 
choice: ${side.choice.error}`);
            } while (!result);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    wincounter[battle.winner || 'draw']++;

    if (DEBUG && i % DEBUG_EVERY === 0) {
      console.log('===BEGIN RANDOM MATCH LOG EXPORT===');
      console.log(battle.log.join('\n'));
      console.log('===END RANDOM MATCH LOG EXPORT===');
      console.log('===BEGIN RANDOM MATCH INPUT LOG EXPORT===');
      console.log(battle.inputLog.join('\n'));
      console.log('===END RANDOM MATCH INPUT LOG EXPORT===');
    }

    battle.destroy();

    if (MAX_TIME && Date.now() - startTime >= MAX_TIME) {
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log(`Simulated ${i} battles in ${Date.now() - startTime}ms.`);
  console.log(`Blue win chance: ${wincounter['Blue'] / i}`);
  console.log(`Red win chance: ${wincounter['Red'] / i}`);
  console.log(`Draw chance: ${wincounter['draw'] / i}`);

  // Large Counts condition
  if (wincounter['Blue'] >= 10 && wincounter['Red'] >= 10) {
    let favoredWinrate = Math.max(wincounter['Blue'], wincounter['Red']) / 
i;
    let standardError = Math.sqrt(favoredWinrate * (1-favoredWinrate) / i);
    console.log(`Margin of error: ${Z_STAR * standardError}`);
  } else {
    console.log("Counts are too small to infer a margin of error.");
  }
}

main();
```

I've filled in all the information of my PC and whatever codes and downloads I was supposed to do stated, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Help would be very greatly appreciated. Thank you. If it would be easier I'll also provide the Github link I've acquired this code from. https://gist.github.com/mathfreak231/4229a28f419f4aa10fcb2eba9fdd57e9

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic, but even if they weren't, you should post a [MCVE], not your whole 300-line script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is just how SO formats it, but there are a few extraneous linebreaks here:

1. On the line with `ruleset: ["PBR Sleep Clause", "PBR Freeze Clause", "PBR Self-Destruct`. The next line begins with `Clause`, which is not a valid JS keyword, and thus the error
2. On the line with `throw new Error("Can't analyze a match unless all the Pokemon have been`, again an unnecessary linebreak.
3. Comment line beginning with `// If this is true, it prints some match logs (1 in DEBUG_EVERY) to stdout` has a linebreak.
4. Comment line beginning with `// Set this to require a .json file to bash a match there instead of a live` has a linebreak.

In general, *please* read the error message more explicitly. It'll almost always explicitly tell you where it believes the error to be.